# Links don't work in PISA

Tags: html, pdf-generation, pisa

Here is a part of my HTML:

```
<h5 id="my-header">Header is a header</h5>

... other stuff ...

<a href="#my-header">go there!</a>
```

I process this using PISA:

```
%PISA_BIN% -s --encoding utf-8 %TITLE%.html %TITLE%.pdf
```

In the resulting PDF, link is not working: it's shown in underlined blue as a usual link, but when I click on it nothing happens. Tested this with Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader and Chrome embedded browser.

Also, in the resulting HTML link works as expected.

What's wrong?